# Can I create an app for the Ubuntu Touch platform using PyQt?

Tags: application-development, python, ubuntu-touch

Will I be able to create an app for the Ubuntu Touch platform targeted at phones and tablets using PyQt?

What are the options for writing apps for Ubuntu Touch using Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For applications to run on tablets/phones (and desktops) we recommend using the [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), which is based on QML.

You might be able to run Python apps from the phone, as the Python runtime will most probably be there, but this will not be supported in principle. This means you might get your Python apps to run, but effectively you'll be on your own.

You might want to try to write a PyQt app for the phone, but I'm not sure how well it supports QML and whether it can integrate with the Ubuntu UI Toolkit (the part of the SDK used to draw the widgets). PySide is out of the question, as it only supports Qt4, and the Ubuntu UI Toolkit uses Qt5.